# Java FX application.css Change text inside radiobuttons/checkboxes

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

http://prntscr.com/kc9hhp I have changed the background and text of Labels using the code:

```
.root{
-fx-background-color: #383838;

  }
.label{
-fx-text-fill:rgb(255,255,255);
 }
```

I am trying to figure out how to change the color of text inside the checkboxes and radiobuttons. I have tried:

```
.radio-toolbar label{
-fx-font-family:"Arial Black", sans-serif;
-fx-font-size:12px;
-fx-text-fill:rgb(255,255,255);
} 
.radiobutton{
-fx-text-fill:rgb(255,255,255);
 }
```

None of the code works. Again, I am trying to change the color of text that is inside of the radiobutton and checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through code:

```
RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("blue text");
rb1.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: blue;");
```

But you have the name of the node wrong... it is this:

```
.radio-button
{
    -fx-text-fill:blue;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering how to do it through the css "application.css".

Comment: I know you can do it that way in the main file

Comment: I've updated my answer... I found out by using this:     System.out.println(rb1.getStyleClass());

Comment: Thank you. I did not know you can use getStyleClass() to find out the name of node

Comment: Taking a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html often helps. Taking a look at `modena.css` is often helpful too...